# How to use Angular 2 in exist Spring MVC project

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, angular

I have a Spring MVC project and use JSP. I want to use Angular 2 but I don't want to disrupt this project.

```
@RequestMapping("")
String AMethod(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    //Doing something

    return a.jsp
}
```

My project something like this. I use lots of JSP.

When I search Angular 2, all examples use one index.html.

I want to create different components with angular 2 and use this component's selector in my JSP files.

But I don't know how can I do that. Because there is no example in anywhere.

How should the code structure be? How can I use Angular 2 like this?

Comment: Do you want to use JSP as well as Angular?

Comment: In **my** opinion: don't mix up JSP and Angular. Either use templating engines like JSP or use Angular and create a RESTful backend.

Comment: Yes, I want to use JSP and Angular 2 together.

Comment: I second @smsnheck, you can do otherwise but with a good reason ;-)

Comment: Exactly @SundararajGovindasamy